# Custom Date Range In Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, date, teradata, dayofweek, sql-date-functions

Can anyone help me create a custom week view? I have a table that gives me sales for each day, but want to be able to view them as a weekly sum.

Where I am running into problems is that I need the week to show data from Friday- Thursday.

I found on another forum this code:

```
CASE WHEN ((Table_date - (000101 (DATE))) + 1) MOD 7 = 6 THEN Table_date + 6
    ELSE   Table_date + (6 - (((Table_date - (000101 (DATE))) + 1) MOD 7+1 )) 
    END AS fri_week_ending_date
```

Which can calculate a Friday week end date, but does anyone know how to adjust it for Thursday week end? I have tried all the options I could guess, but my data then seems to be off. Or if there is an easier way to create these custom week views I am open to any ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your existing calculation is way too complicated .

There's `NEXT_DAY` which returns the next weekday:

```
Next_Day(Table_date-1, 'fri')
```

Must be `Table_date-1` to return the same date when it's a friday.

Simply switch to `Next_Day(Table_date-1, 'thu')` for Thursday :-)